# IntelliJ struggles with huge files.. tips for improvement?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I work with files with 30,000+ lines in Java all the time, and IntelliJ seriously struggles to keep up. It makes my entire machine unusable, and it's a 10-core/20-thread i7 with 64GB RAM...

What are some tips to improve the performance of IntelliJ when working with giant class files? I already dedicate 16GB RAM via `-Xmx16g -Xms16g` in `idea.exe.vmoptions` and `idea64.exe.vmoptions`

Comment: I have a similar problem right now.  The thing for me is that I'm using the 32 bit version of IntelliJ for a number of reasons, so I can only allocate so much RAM +1.

Comment: *I work with files with 30,000+ lines in Java all the time*. There's your real problem right there.

Comment: Probably a slow drive

Comment: @shmosel It's legacy code, there's no reason that IntelliJ shouldn't have the capability to deal with it.

Comment: @shmosel I'm not sure that one 30000 line file would perform worse than thirty 1000 line files, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Presumably you wouldn't be working with all 30 at once. Anyway, I'm not justifying IntelliJ's behavior, just pointing out another angle worth considering. P.S. I work with plenty of files like this too. :)

Comment: @JonathanBeaudoin I would be surprised if it wasn't loading it all into memory.

Comment: I can't for the life of me imagine such a Java file size! What do you have in there, just methods and classes? There are standards to be followed as per lines per method, methods per class, etc. That said, I think any editor, including Sublime and Atom will kneel down before such a size, and so will the nuts of my brain in fact.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The file is simply too big. Even 3000 lines is too much, refactor it.

You can easily diagnose that you have enough of heap, by enabling `Memory Indicator` in settings, or by using VisualVM.

However the problem is probably not memory related, but Syntax/Inspection related. You can try to enable `Power Save Mode` (Main Menu | File) to see if it helps. 
Syntax check and Inspections can be disabled per file using this button:

[image]

Also if you hover over the colored box in the right upper editor corner, you can see what those inspections are doing... Chances are, you will see some correlations.

You could also try CPU Sampling in VisualVM, you might recognize what the IDE is doing simply by the name of a class and perhaps disable some plugin or feature.

Or just report a performance problem - https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241235-Reporting-performance-problems